# In-app-purchase just won't work

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am currently trying to configure my app for in app purchase, but it just won't work. Every time I try to start the purchase flow it says "This version of the applications is not configured for billing through Google Play". I am quite sure that I walked through al necessary steps to make it work. I also tested SKU-Id "android.test.purchased", which works fine.

- `base64EncodedPublicKey` is def. correct and exactly teh same like the code from the developer console
- I did not forget `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` in my manifest
- I have applied the google account that I am using on my testing device as a tester account in the developer console
- I am using the exactly same APK on my device an in the developer console. I installed it on my device via `adb -d install`

So any ideas what I could have done wrong?

This is my code:
(onCreate)

```
base64EncodedPublicKey
        iabHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        iabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                      if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                         // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                         Log.d(PURCHASE_TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                      } else if (result.isSuccess()){
                         // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                        Log.d(PURCHASE_TAG, "Setup completed: " + result);
                        iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, null, queryFinishedListener);
                      }
                   }

                });
```

(onActivityResult)

```
if (iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
            return;
        }
```

(Button click for starting burchase flow)

```
if(isPremium){
                saveImageToGallery(imageState.image);
            } else if (iabHelper != null) {
                iabHelper.flagEndAsync();
                purchaseItem(SKU_TEST);
```

(purchaseItem())

```
private void purchaseItem(String sku) {
        iabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 10001,   
                   purchaseFinishedListener);
    }
```

(listeners)

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener 
       queryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
       public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)   
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
             // handle error
             return;
           } else if (result.isSuccess()){
               Log.d("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$", "" + result);
           }
       }
    };

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener purchaseFinishedListener 
       = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d("ERROR_TAG", "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
          }      
          else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_TEST)) {
             // give user access to premium content and update the UI
              isPremium = purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_TEST);        
          }
       }

    };
```

Comment: Are you running the app from your IDE?

Comment: No, as I said above "I installed it on my device via `adb -d install`".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the key store you signed your apk. You must use same key store for apk that has uploaded to Google Play and test.

Comment: As I already said, I am using the exact same APK for both, developer console and device. I exported it from Eclipse and signed it with a valid key store.

Comment: No, that is not possible. As I said: I have exported the apk from eclipse and afterwards I used the SAME apk to upload it to Google developer console and install it on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem, I fixed it by:

1. Go to play store developer console

   2. Settings > Manage Testers, then add your another test email, not the one you use in publishing apps.
   3. Again under Developer Console, Account Details (scroll down) > License Testing and add the emails of your users who will test your 
      app.
   4. On your device, login in play store with one of the test emails [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS1ml.png) you allowed.
   5. Launch you app and make in app purchase. There should be fixed.

more https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

**Summary:**

[image]

[image]